# Nuevo metodo en controlador

Tags: laravel-5

Buen dia

Queria preguntar, si es posible agregar un nuevo metodo tipo POST aun controlador resource que ya tiene sus metodos edit, destroy, store.

He tratado de hacerlo asi pero no quiere agreagar la ruta.

```
Route::post('/panel/usuario', 'UsuarioController@entrada')->name('usuario.entrada');
Route::resource('/panel/usuario', 'UsuarioController');
```

Comment: Como tal, si es posible. La cosa es que quieres que haga ese metodo. Si va a insertar el mismo resource puede ser redundante. Si es para insertar un valor relacionado puede ser incluso conveniente hacerlo en ese controlador. Que error te da?

Comment: pero no veo lógico que ambas rutas tengan el mismo nombre, a lo que voy es el método `post` debería estar apuntando a un ruta similar pero no igual ; finalmente aunque la ruta cambie va a apuntar al mismo Controlador

Comment: Tiene que revisar la ruta nueva que esta creando tal vez se solapen

Comment: como ya te mencioné antes ambas rutas son la misma desde ahi empieza el problema, debería bastar con que cambies el nombre a alguna de las dos

Comment: Tienes razon Daniel, tenia que diferenciar esa ruta, tan pronto lo cambie dejo de aparecer ese error.. es que mi intension es poder seleccionar un nombre de un select y despues darle enviar, para que me busque todos los registros referentes a ese nombre que seleccione, pero mi formulario parece que no envia nada, muestro mis archivos.

Comment: Controller: https://paste.laravel.io/ab633feb-024e-41dc-9e43-73ebca920c61        view: https://paste.laravel.io/53b6a215-f1cb-4011-a366-ad563ca6dec1               error: Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), 0 passed in C:\laragon\www\crudgobernaciontres\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illu            internfaz:  https://ibb.co/iT83B9

Comment: Ya lo he arreglado.. muchas gracias por su ayuda